# Parsing log text

Tags: javascript, regex, linux, pattern-matching

I have this log text:

```
1. SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.37447.2.1.1.1 type=4  value=STRING: "Test warn level"
2. SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.37447.2.1.1.2 type=4  value=STRING: "WARN"
3. SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.37447.2.1.1.3 type=4  value=STRING: "PSBA2STOR051"  
4. SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.37447.2.1.1.4 type=4  value=STRING: "AF-201969" 
5. SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.37447.2.1.1.5 type=4  value=STRING: "PSBA2STOR051" 
6. SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.37447.2.1.1.6 type=4  value=STRING: "117813866" 
7. SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.37447.2.1.1.7 type=4  value=STRING: "test"  
8. SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.37447.2.1.1.8 type=4  value=STRING: "test"
```

Note that the order numbers doesn't exist in my log

and I need to extract only

```
Test warn level
test
test
```

Result needs to be : Test warn level:test-test

I've tried this :

```
(SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.37447.2.1.1.1.*)\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n(.*SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.37447.2.1.1.7.*)\n(.*SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.37447.2.1.1.8.*)
```

But it doesn't work like I need it returns the hole line

Comment: What language/tool are you using? What are the criteria to select the right values?

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
sed -e 's/.*37447.2.1.1.[178].*"\(.*\)"/\1/;t;d' test.log
```

The regex search for lines containing 37447.2.1.1.1, .7 or .8: `37447.2.1.1.[178]`

In theses lines, take only what is between the quotes: `"\(.*\)"`

The not matched lines (`t`) are suppressed (`d`): `t;d`

Comment: i forgot to mention i need it in javascript

Answer (score 0):

Using:

```
/"(Test warn level|test)"+\s*$/gm
```

you can detect

```
"Test warn level"
"test"  
"test"
```

and `$1` you can omit the double-quotes and whitespace.

See https://regexr.com/4ha3r

Answer (score 0):

This expression might likely extract our desired values,

```
.*?37447\.2\.1\.1\.[817].*?value=string\s*:\s*"([^"]+)"
```

using this capturing group `([^"]+)`.

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/mZCvIZ/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/mZCvIZ/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs step by step, if you like.

Answer (score 0):

You get the match for the whole line because you use `.*` after matching the start text.

From your example, it seems you want to get 3 capturing groups using the start of the `SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.37447.2.1.1.1` and specify the last number which could be 1, 7 or 8.

This might seem like a large pattern (and it can be shortened), but you might make use of negative lookaheads to check if the line does not contain a value that you want to match.

If it does not, then match the whole line. Else capture the value between double quotes in a group.

```
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises\.37447\.2\.1\.1\.1 [^"]+"([^"]+)"(?:\n(?!SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises\.37447\.2\.1\.1\.7).*)*\nSNMPv2-SMI::enterprises\.37447\.2\.1\.1\.7[^"]+"([^"]+)"\nSNMPv2-SMI::enterprises\.37447\.2\.1\.1\.8 [^"]+"([^"]+)"
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uSeYaq/1)

To get your result in Javascript, you could use those 3 capturing groups:

```js
const regex = /SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises\.37447\.2\.1\.1\.1 [^"]+"([^"]+)"(?:\n(?!SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises\.37447\.2\.1\.1\.7).*)*\nSNMPv2-SMI::enterprises\.37447\.2\.1\.1\.7[^"]+"([^"]+)"\nSNMPv2-SMI::enterprises\.37447\.2\.1\.1\.8 [^"]+"([^"]+)"/;
const str = `SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.37447.2.1.1.1 type=4  value=STRING: "Test warn level"
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.37447.2.1.1.2 type=4  value=STRING: "WARN"
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.37447.2.1.1.3 type=4  value=STRING: "PSBA2STOR051"
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.37447.2.1.1.4 type=4  value=STRING: "AF-201969"
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.37447.2.1.1.5 type=4  value=STRING: "PSBA2STOR051"
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.37447.2.1.1.6 type=4  value=STRING: "117813866"
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.37447.2.1.1.7 type=4  value=STRING: "test"
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.37447.2.1.1.8 type=4  value=STRING: "test"`;
let res = str.match(regex);
console.log(`${res[1]}:${res[2]}-${res[3]}`)
```